# Scheduled PowerShell Task Won't Write to a File

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell script that runs exactly the way I want interactively; creating two log files: one is a csv for graphing the output later, and the other is a basic status log, such as:

```
Opening database connection at 01/27/2015 09:11:47
Site analysis started.
Successfully recorded site metrics.
```

My scheduled task runs the PowerShell successfully, and commits all my entries to a SQL DB, but my csv and txt log are not completed.

I am using **Write-Output** and **Out-File**

My logs are set as such:

```
$LogFilePath = $("L:\Scripts\Metrics\Site_Analysis.csv")
$StatusLogFilePath = $("L:\Scripts\Metrics\Site_Analysis_Status.log")
```

The PowerShell script runs in:

```
C:\Scripts\
```

I really don't want to create a batch file that simply outputs everything such as:

```
batchfile.bat > file.log
```

since the desired output is very specific, and I don't want verbose output.

I found this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25311489/scheduled-powershell-task-wont-write-to-file

but even with the log files set to the same directory, it still did not output.

Thanks.

Edit @ 9:22AM - 1/27/2015:

Please note that all csv and log file output is historical (output is appended).

Comment: Try to give Full Permission on Scripts folder to the account that is running the script.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I gave full permissions on the directory and recursively to the child items, to the account running the PowerShell Script, but it did not resolve the issue.

Comment: Ok, in all fairness, I don't know if I should delete this question until I figure out what is going on now. My scheduled task was working, but now it is not, so I will need to fix this first.

Comment: Can I delete this question somehow? I don't want it to confuse anyone. It turns out that the scheduled task path had quotes that were an invalid character type. I had copy/paste it from the command prompt and I just noticed they looked different than a normal ". It works now that I replaced them. The log files output fine too! I apologize for the misstep.

Comment: raredesign: you can post the above comment as an answer. It might help other people who are in similar situation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't want it to confuse anyone, but it turns out that the scheduled task path had quotes that were an invalid character type. I had copy/paste it from the command prompt and I just noticed they looked different than a normal ". It works now that I replaced them. The log files output fine too! Even though it was a misstep, hopefully this helps someone in the future.